# For N-day moving average, how is N parameter called?

Tags: statistics, terminology, average

I'm looking for a good name for the variable. Average window length? Sounds like a term for a glass cutter.

Comment: "glass cutter" :D  I think that window length is certainly descriptive enough, given the context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Window length" is used without comment on [the Wikipedia page for moving averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and it's been there for quite a while without being edited out (despite the page getting other edits), so I think that suggests that "window length" is a fine way to refer to this idea.